# What is the < tag for?

Tags: javascript, mustache, hogan.js

I'm using twitter's [Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) implementation of the [Mustache templating language](http://mustache.github.io/). What is the `<` tag for?

You can see reference to the tag in [compiler.js line 341](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/blob/master/lib/compiler.js#L341):

```
'<': function(node, context) {
      var ctx = {partials: {}, code: '', subs: {}, inPartial: true};
      Hogan.walk(node.nodes, ctx);
      var template = context.partials[createPartial(node, context)];
      template.subs = ctx.subs;
      template.partials = ctx.partials;
    },
```

There aren't many comments around this section, and I can't figure it out.

**If I use the `<` tag in my template, what will it do?**

Comment: Thats a name of a function. It will be called like `Hogan.codegen['<'](node, context);`

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I know that, but I want to know what the function does, i.e; if I use the `<` tag in my template, what will it do?

Comment: okay... your question sounds like a little bit other

Comment: What seems to happen when you try using it?

Comment: @admdrew I used it in place of `>` (partial), and my partial was included. However, there must be a difference in use between the 2 tags because the code is different.

Comment: @Drahcir Ahh interesting. (also, Googling `hogan mustache "less than"` returns a lot of very unrelated/amusing results)

Comment: @admdrew When I tried that search I just got info about the hulk's house sale :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much Googling I found the answer, it's a clever template inheritance method (just what I was hoping it was).

I found [this issue](https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/38) & accompanying [gist](https://gist.github.com/spullara/1854699), it explains the problem and their suggested solution. It seems this functionality has been implemented in hogan.js, but is not part of the official Mustache spec yet.

This functionality doesn't work with the currently published version on npm (2.0.0), instead you need to use version 3.0.0 from github. Version 2 just treats `<` & `>` the same.

---

#### Example:

Main template (*template.html*):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{$title}}Default Title{{/title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{$content}}<p>Default Content</p>{{/content}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Content template (*content.html*):

```
{{<template}}
    {{$title}}Override title{{/title}}
    {{$content}}
        <div>
            <h1>Override Content</h1>
        </div>
        {{>anotherPartial}}
    {{/content}}
{{/template}}
```

Now all you need to do is render *content.html*, and it will be included in *template.html* as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Override title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Override Content</h1>
        </div>
        {{>anotherPartial}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Note the usage of `$` tags which are replaced by the same tags in `content.html`.

This functionality makes it really easy to render views in multiple formats, perhaps for different devices. It also removes the need for dynamic partial names (as many people want).

Comment: Exactly. This feature is implemented, at least, by Hogan.js, https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java (java implementation), and http://github.com/groue/GRMustache (objective-c implementation)